# (SQLAlchemy/SQLModel) After changing schema, transaction not appearing the database after commit

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlmodel

I'm  making a multitenancy fastapi application (SQLModel). The strucuture I'm also going to use is multiple schemas, so I require a schema change sometimes.

The tenant schema's are set up as:

```
class SysEmailModel(BaseTenantSchemaModel, table=True):
```

The class where this is based on contains the schema:

```
class BaseTenantSchemaModel(BaseSharedSchemaModel, table=False):
    metadata = MetaData(
        schema="agip_tenant"
    )
```

The class used here is not relevant, and is based on `SQLModel`. I choose `metadata` over `__table_args__` for then in relations you don't  need to add the schema name.

To change the schema I use:

```
def getSession(which):
    ....
    # the session here is a session with a created engine
    connectable = database_session_tenant.connection(
        execution_options={
            "schema_translate_map": {"agip_tenant": "SOME_NAME"}
        }
    )

    return Session(connectable)
```

**The issue:**

When I have made a record and add it to the table, after the commit the data is not in the database. The row created is in memory of the application, and it does query the data correctly. See the following code:

```
# define a row
session = getSession(tenant)
row = SysEmailModel(
        ....
    )
    
a = session.query(SysEmailModel).all()
print(a) #prints one row which is correct
session.add(row)
print(row) #prints row with no id, correct
session.commit()
session.refresh(row)
print(row) #prints row with id, and this is indeed increased with 1
b = session.query(SysEmailModel).all()
print(b) #prints 2 rows which is connect
```

Executing a `select` on the database shows one row.

**The question**

What can be wrong here?
Could it be that setting the schema this way needs more information in the `execution_options`?

**Package versions**

- sqlmodel==0.0.14
- pydantic==1.10.13
- pydantic_core==2.10.1
- SQLAlchemy==2.0.23
- sqlalchemy2-stubs==0.0.2a36
- fastapi==0.105.0

** Current Solution **

The current solution is to also redefine the connection itself instead of editing the connection from the session. So in the `getSession` I've defined, I now do the following:

```
engine = create_engine(...)
execution_options = dict(tenant=SOME_NAME)
connectable = engine.execution_options(schema_translate_map=schema_translate_map)

return Session(connectable)
```

Offcourse, the new question then is:
Am I not now getting way to many connections, or should I add `close` each time.

Comment: `tenant.commit()`? Shouldn't you use `session.commit()` instead of that?

Comment: @YuriiMotov Correct, I quickly edited the sample above. I had changed the code for easier reading and made a mistake writing this down. Thanks for pointing it out.